# Delete first and last line or record from file using sed

Tags: sed, awk

I want to delete first and last line from the file

file1 code :

```
H|ACCT|XEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845|

849002|48|1208004|1

849007|28|1208004|1

T|2
```

After delete the output should be

```
849002|48|1208004|1

849007|28|1208004|1
```

I have tried below method but has to run it 2 times, I want one liner solution to remove both in one go!

```
sed '1,1d' file1.txt  >> file1.out
sed '$d' file1.out  >> file2
```

Please suggest one liner code....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
sed '$d' < file1.txt | sed "1d"
```

Comment: The addition of the ; below (from @CodeGnome and @darque) would make it even better!

Answer (score 38):

You could use `;`

```
sed '1d; $d' file
```

Answer (score 12):

#### Use Command Separator

In sed, you can separate commands using a semicolon. For example:

```
sed '1d; $d' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `sed -i '1d;$d' /path/to/file`

Answer (score -1):

```
awk 'NR>2{print v}{v=$0}'
```

Starting with line 3, print the previous line each time. This means the first and last lines will not be printed.