# Excluding/ignoring (Not Deleting) first and last line based on line number

Tags: linux, sed

I'm using sed command to edit some text file.

How can i exclude the first and last line in each text file for being edited.

I went through sed gnu manual but i only found commands to match line ranges i.e. 1,$ or to exclude ranges i.e. 1,$!. i just need to exclude line # 1 and last line $. i'm not sure if its possible to select a range i.e 2, $-1?

Here's my code.

```
sed -e '1,$ s/.*/<p>&<\/p>/'' file.txt
```

Comment: You could also use head and tail to pre-process the stream for sed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete first and last line or record from file using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14913669/608639), [How do I delete the first n lines and last line of a file using shell commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209068/56041), etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use maths in sed addresses. But you can tell sed to do nothing on the first and last line:

```
sed -e '1n; $n; s/.*/<p>&<\/p>/'
```

where `n` means "read the next line of input into the pattern space" (in case of the last line, it won't read anything).

(The two single quotes at the end of the expression are probably a typo, right?)